# unclassified method java.util.Base64 encode byte[]

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.Base64

//other code

String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(password.getBytes())
```

Where `password` is a String.

For this, I am getting:

```
unclassified method java.util.Base64 encode byte[]
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: 'Unclassified'? Really? Sure it doesn't say 'undefined'? You must report  error messages accurately.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the class `java.util.Base64` doesn't have the `encode` method. Read the java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html). However Apache Commons offers a [Base64 utility class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/BaseNCodec.html#encode(byte[])) that has the exact method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use Base64 from java.util in a way Base64 from Apache commons is used (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html).

Either use Apache commons or read javadocs for java.util.Base64.